# How to notify a component that it needs to update

Tags: reactjs, performance, setinterval

As you can see in the code below, I check every 100ms (using `setInterval`) whether a change has been made to `convertProgress`, and if so, the component needs to update.

```
class TradingThing extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { convertProgress, setConvertProgress } = this.props.store; // mobx store
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
         if(convertProgress < 100) {
             setConvertProgress(Math.min(convertProgress + 5, 100));
         }
    , 100);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>Progress from MobX state: {this.props.store.convertProgress}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I handle it?
Is it okay to call an empty function every 100ms?

Note: I am not allowed to call `setState`function in `render`, `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate` and `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`.

Comment: Why do you have to call this every 100ms? Can't you trigger an event when the progress is completed?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Thanks for your interest. I need to reset the timer according to a `prop` is changed from `false` to `true`. I want to know about the cost of counting every 100ms. :D

Comment: Is it possible for you to utilize some kind of a pub-sub mechanism? That will be much more performant than using `setInterval`

Comment: @YoavKadosh Sorry. What does 'pub-sub' mean?

Comment: Publish - Subscribe pattern. You can use it to "notify" you're component when it needs to update, instead of polling every 100ms. Kind of like how events work in JavaScript. Once the progress = 100, an event will be triggered, and your component (which will be listening to that event) will update at that moment.

Comment: I can write a code example, I just need to make sure that I understand your use case - are you updating the component when the progress changes? Or when it reaches 100%?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. I am poor in English and javascript. Could you provide some codes or make your answer to my question?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Yes. I need to update my component when progress is changed and reaches 100%. And in current codes, the component is updating when progress is changed by mobx store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of polling every `100ms`, a better approach is to utilize some kind of [Publish-Subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) mechanism. This mechanism allows you to "notify" your component when it needs to update, instead of constantly (and redundantly) checking whether an update is needed.

Events in JavaScript are a good example of the Publish-Subscribe pattern.

There are many ways to implement that, but here is a basic example of the concept:

```
// This class is utilizing the publish-subscribe pattern
class ProgressUpdater {
  static subscribers = [];

  static publish(progress) {
    this.subscribers.forEach(s => s(progress));
  }

  static subscribe(subscriber) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriber);
  }
}
```

Then your process should publish its progress by calling:

```
ProgressUpdater.publish(progress);
```

And your component should `subscribe` to the progress update event in `componentDidMount`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {progress: 0}

  componentDidMount() {
    ProgressUpdater.subscribe(progress => {
        this.setState({progress});
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='progress'>Progress: {this.state.progress}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hampgto0/) to see how it all works together

Comment: Great article for pub-sub mechanism! I have learned a lot! Thanks!